# Access Post Variable in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a commenting system that uses ajax.

It generates a div with comments and a reply box via a php loop, meaning the form is repeated over and over again. How do I get var parent to only take the data from the form I submitted? not all of the form fields with the id parent.

```
$(function () {
    $('.reply').on('submit', function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/app/reply',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                var parent = $('#parent').val();
                $("#comment_"+parent).append(data);
                var form = document.getElementById("form_" + parent);
                form.reset();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="reply" id="form_<?php echo $comment['id'] ?>">
    <textarea id="textArea"  name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="upload_btn" value="Reply">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post ?>" name="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $comment['id'] ?>" id ="parent" name="parent">
    <input type="hidden" value="pop" name="location">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $level ?>" name="level">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove `id=parent` from hidden field then you can access like this;

```
<script>
$('.reply').on('submit', function (e) {
    var that    =   this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            var parent = $(that).find('input[name=parent]').val();
            //your code
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass your data in AJAX like this:

```
...
type: 'post',
url: '/app/reply',
data: { 'x': '1973' },
success: function (data) {
...
```

then you can collect it in PHP this way:

```
$year = $_POST['x']; // will be set to the string '1973'
```

From here you should be able to find and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem, the issue is with `var parent = $('#parent').val();`. This line always returns the same value regardles of which scope `$.ajax()` function was called.
Safe way to solve this may be passing id of form from which you are calling `$.ajax()` function into it and then do the query using this value.
This will be something like that:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/app/reply',
    _formId: this.id
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      var parent = $('#div_prefix'+this._formId).val(); //Now you have diferent parent                      for every form
      ...
    }
});
```